# Function pointer questions

Tags: c, gcc, atmel, cortex-m

I'm trying to implement some code in an Atmel datasheet. I have directly copied it from the datasheet below.

```
 (unsigned int) (*IAP_Function)(unsigned long);
    void main (void)
{
    unsigned long FlashSectorNum = 200; //
    unsigned long flash_cmd = 0;
    unsigned long flash_status = 0;
    unsigned long EFCIndex = 0; // 0:EEFC0, 1: EEFC1

    /* Initialize the function pointer (retrieve function address from NMI vecto*/
    IAP_Function = ((unsigned long) (*)(unsigned long))0x00800008;
    /* Send your data to the sector here */
    /* build the command to send to EEFC */
    flash_cmd = (0x5A << 24) | (FlashSectorNum << 8) | AT91C_MC_FCMD_EWP;
    /* Call the IAP function with appropriate command */
    flash_status = IAP_Function (EFCIndex, flash_cmd);
    }
```

This enables me to call a function in ROM to program the flash that runs the code in the micro.

I'm using the gcc for ARM Cortex and get an error for the first line:

> expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘unsigned’

Now, I just changed that to:

```
unsigned int (*IAP_Function)(unsigned long);
```

As it looked wrong (not sure why the return value from a function should be in brwackets) and that error went away.

However, this line:

```
IAP_Function = ((unsigned long) (*)(unsigned long))0x00800008;
```

Throws up the error:

> expected expression before ‘)’ token

With the cursor being by the ) next to the *.

Unsurprisingly, I also get the error:

> too many arguments to function ‘IAP_Function’

For the line:

```
flash_status = IAP_Function (EFCIndex, flash_cmd);
```

I suspect the datasheet has been poorly written in terms of that last error and, indeed, the first error.

However, the line:

```
IAP_Function = ((unsigned long) (*)(unsigned long))0x00800008;
```

I do not understand. I believe, it is trying to get the *contents* of 0x00800008, and use that as the pointer to the function.  If that is correct, how should I write that line?

Also, are my other assumptions correct in terms of ignoring the brackets around unsigned int in the first line for the value returned from the function? Also, I assume I should just change that first line to be:

```
unsigned int (*IAP_Function)(unsigned long, unsigned long);
```

As the function call needs two values?

Many thanks :)

Comment: `unsigned int` is a single type, you don't need (nor should you use) parentheses around it. Also, you have a mismatch in that `IAP_Function` is declared as a pointer to a function returning `unsigned int`, but in your case you have it returning `unsigned long`.

Comment: I should reiterate that the code above is *not* my code; it is taken directly from the Atmel datasheet and I realise there are discrepancies. I am trying to ascertain whether I am correctly understand and correcting the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line `IAP_Function = ((unsigned long) (*)(unsigned long))0x00800008;` casts integer to a function pointer address and assigns it to `IAP_Function`. Cast is required, because any self-respecting compiler should throw warning if you try to assign integer to pointer without a cast.

But as you noted return type doesn't match and for some reason there are parenthesis around it. So proper cast would look like:

```
IAP_Function = (unsigned int (*)(unsigned long))0x00800008;
```

And if you need another parameter, do add that also. Datasheet code examples are often lies, so do read carefully what manual says about the function parameters.

You should consider declaring `typedef` of function pointer to make sense out of this madness:

```
typedef unsigned (*FuncType)(unsigned long, unsigned long);
FuncType IAP_Function;
...
IAP_Function = (FuncType)0x00800008; // Nice and simple
```

Comment: Removing one set of the parentheses from the line IAP_Function = ((unsigned long) (*)(unsigned long))0x00800008; did, indeed, do the trick. It then simply through up a warning about the incorrect return value which I was aware of. So thanks for that. What I was failing to comprehend was how it was casting - in that there was the return value as well as the setting up the address of where the function lives in ROM. Many thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `IAP_Function = ((unsigned long) (*)(unsigned long))0x00800008;` doesn't uses content of 0x00800008 as a pointer to function. It uses 0x00800008 as the address itself.

In your definition you declared `IAP_Function` as a function that returns `unsigned int`, however, when you're casting you cast to function that returns `unsigned long`.

Also, function takes just one argument and you're passing two. You should either change your cast and function declaration or pass only one argument.

Comment: I did say above that I think I should change the function declaration to have two arguments and was asking for confirmation. And one again, I reiterate, this is *not* my code and realise that it [the function pointer] returns a 16-bit value, not 32-bit.

As far as IAP_Function = ((unsigned long) (*)(unsigned long))0x00800008; is concerned, if it is just using 0x00800008 why on earth doesn't it just use IAP_Function = 0x00800008? Are they obfuscating just for the sake of it do you think?!

Comment: You may assume my words as a confirmation. I'm not sure you can as easily cast number to pointer `IAP_Function = 0x00800008`, so cast is needed. Function pointer doesn't return anything. Furthermore, as far as I know for all cortex-m processors, size of int is 32 bits. So, in any case, function doesn't return 16 bit.

Answer (score 0):

To match the call at the bottom, the function pointer declaration at the top should be

```
unsigned long (*IAP_Function)(unsigned long, unsigned long);
```

However, the correct thing to do depends on the function that is assigned to the pointer, which you have not described.

Answer (score -1):

It is out of the primary topic, but I report my result, as I found first this page for my original problem with the IAP_Function() in question. 
After some tries I successfully used the IAP_Function() (a clear GPNVM Bit operation) with SAM3A8C, in the following way. The address in not 0x00800008, but 0x00100008 (I found this tip elsewhere), and IAP_Function() takes only one long argument, as described in chapter 20.5.2 of the Atmel manual. I don't know if the 0x00800008 address works similarly, but with two arguments (with EFCIndex), or these are mistypings in the manual.